# gem list -r finds nothing

Tags: ruby, list, rubygems

```
gem list -r ra
```

=> *** REMOTE GEMS ***
but no gems appear

```
gem list
```

=> (my installed gems)

```
ruby -v
```

=> ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

```
gem -v
```

=> 2.7.3

```
gem environment
```

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.3
- RUBY VERSION: 2.5.0 (2017-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rubies/2.5.0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/xxx/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rubies/2.5.0/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /home/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - /usr/local/rubies/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - "gem" => "--no-document"
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - /home/xxx/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin
  - /usr/local/rubies/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin
  - /usr/local/rubies/2.5.0/bin
  - /home/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.1/bin
  - /usr/local/heroku/bin
  - /home/xxx/commands
  - /home/xxx/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /usr/bin
  - /sbin
  - /bin
  - /usr/games
  - /usr/local/games
  - /snap/bin

I haven't changed anything (that I'm aware of) in my ruby since when it did work. Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: can't install any gems. Example:
      gem install rubyfann-1.2.6
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rubyfann-1.2.6' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

    changed my .gemrc 
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
benchmark: false
gem: "--no-rdoc --no-ri"

    gem list -r ^rails
still empty

uninstalled ruby. Reinstalled with ruby 2.5.1 - same problem

Answer (score 0):

well looks like you have no sources. see in gem env `"gem" => "--no-document"`

try running this:

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

my env differs by:

```
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org/"]
     - "benchmark" => false
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
```

can you paste output of `~/.gemrc` to make sure?  Mine looks like:

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
benchmark: false
gem: "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
```

If this doesn't work, perhaps try installing ruby using rvm https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: ---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
benchmark: false
gem: "--no-rdoc --no-ri"

Comment: please modify ~/.gemrc to match `- https://rubygems.org/` after sources. What you have also fails for me when I try what you have.